# Why is SMTP working on local host but not when I deploy online?

Tags: server, smtp, gmail

I have set up SMPT on python and, when I send a message locally, it works.
But when I deploy the application online, I get the exception error.
I have seen a number of solutions online but none of them seem to work for me.
Can somebody help me out please?

This is my python code below

```
def send_email(subject, msg):

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
    server.sendmail(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_ADDRESS, message)
    server.quit()
    print("Success: Email sent!")
    global sent
    sent = True
except:
    print("Email failed to send.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting providers block outgoing SMTP in the cloud. You can get around this by using a Web API instead like Mailgun, or getting a Web API for your SMTP server using a tool like Flute Mail or open-source Postal.